# How to convert VirtualBox VM to OpenStack?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtual-machines, cloud, openstack

I'm running OpenStack in Ubuntu Server 11.10 (installation did using [devstack](https://github.com/cloudbuilders/devstack) script), but I have some virtual machines that are already running using VirtualBox.
How can I convert the VirtualBox machines to run in OpenStack and what is the best way to do it so I won't lose data when stop/restart these machines on OpenStack?

Answer (score 4):

This shouldn't be to hard, do an export in virtual box as described [here](http://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=13838)

Then do an import on OpenStack as suggested [here](http://docs.ganeti.org/ganeti/master/html/design-ovf-support.html)

Use Open Visualization Format as your export type and you should be OK.  Depending on the size of your VM it may take a while, so plan for downtime.